# Change the version number from 97 to 98 in an XML file

Tags: sed, xml, xmlstarlet

I want to change the version number with respect to the ip. For example for this ip `10.228.134.226`, it should change the version number from `97` to `98`

```xml
<qa:browsers> 
    <browser name="firefox" defaultVersion="96" defaultPlatform="Windows 10">
        <version number="97" platform="Windows 10">
            <region name="EU_CENTRAL">
                <host name="10.228.134.226" port="4444" count="1"/>
            </region>
        </version>
        <version number="97" platform="Windows 8">
            <region name="EU_CENTRAL">
                <host name="10.228.134.229" port="4444" count="1"/>
            </region>
        </version>
        <version number="97" platform="Windows 7">
            <region name="EU_CENTRAL">
                <host name="10.228.134.238" port="4444" count="1"/>
            </region>
        </version>
    </browser>
</qa:browsers>
```

Here I want to change the value of `defaultVersion` so how do we do that ?

Comment: Your first paragraph and title seem to be at odds with your question at the end. What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: You've tagged with [tag:xmlstarlet] so you clearly know a good tool for the job. What have you tried? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Using `xmlstarlet` to change the `number` attribute of the `version` node that has a `region/host` sub-node with a `name` attribute with value `10.228.134.226`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//version[region/host/@name = "10.228.134.226"]/@number' \
    -v 98 file >file.new
```